# If $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a ball and $\sigma \in \partial B(0,1)$, if $y=r\sigma $, what is $dy$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B(0,r)=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid \|x\|<r\}\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a $n-$ball and $\sigma \in \partial B(0,1)$ (the bound of $B(0,1)$). If $y=r\sigma $, what is $dy$ ? I would say something like $dy=r r^{d-1}d\sigma $, but I'm not really sure.

In other word, why
$$\frac{1}{|\partial B_1|}\int_{\partial B_1}f(R\sigma )d\sigma =\frac{1}{|\partial B_R|}\int_{\partial B_R}f(y)dy\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

Integration in $\mathbb R^n$. Cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates for $B(0,R)$:

$$
\int_{|x|<R}f(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^Rr^{n-1}\,dr\int_{|\sigma|=1}f(r\sigma)\,d\sigma.
$$ 
Here $d\sigma$ is $(n-1)-$dimensional surface integral on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$.

A convincing and rigorous explanation is given in Walter Rudin's, *Real and Complex Analysis*, Chapter 8, Exercise 6.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand all. Why $$\frac{1}{|\partial B_1|}\int_{\partial B_1}f(R\sigma )d\sigma =\frac{1}{|\partial B_R|}\int_{\partial B_R}f(y)dy\ \ ?$$ I tryed to apply your formula, but it's not conclusive.

Comment: In your formula, both Right and left hand side represent the average of $f$ on the surface $\partial B_R$.